# p adjustment method using dunnettTest (PMCMRplus)

Tags: r

I have a major problem: I am an absolute beginner in R programming :) using libaray PMCMRplus I want to perform a dunnetTest. However, I cant change the methods to adjust the p value. Whatever command I've used I will allways get a single-stept adjustment. Can please anyone help me?? The commant I am using is:

```
dunnettTest(v~Gruppe, alternative="greater", p.adjust.methods ="BH")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late but three inputs to your question that may help:

1.) For `v~Gruppe` have you specified what content should be used? You can define this by using `$` such as `v~Gruppe$columnofyourdataframe`

2.) Also for `v~Gruppe`: according to the PMCMRplus [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PMCMRplus/versions/1.4.1/topics/dunnettTest) you have to use `dunnettTest(x, g)`. You use `v` instead of `x` and did not define `g`.

3.) For `alternative="greater"` have you tried to further specify by using `alternative = c("two.sided", "greater", "less")`? This is also explained in the PMCMRplus [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PMCMRplus/versions/1.4.1/topics/dunnettTest).